# Does AWS Device Farm support OpenCV library?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-device-farm, python-appium

I have created appium-python test cases to test my application on AWS Device Farm. They are working fine on my local machine but I am getting a parsing error when I am trying to run them on Device Farm. I created an empty test case and uploaded on AWS Device Farm and it got accepted but when I uploaded the test bundle after including OpenCV library it gave a parsing error. Is there any way I can use OpenCV on Device Farm?

I have changed prefix of all the libraries in wheels folder whose prefix was not -none-any.whl to -none-any.whl.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into AWS Device Farm's [Custom Environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/custom-test-environments.html). With Custom Environment's your tests will not be parsed, and you're able to edit a YAML file to ensure that your environment has the right dependencies and the tests are ran as you expect.

Comment: I think the error might be coming from uploading the test package and not starting the run. If that the case they'll need to use the NODE_JS test type cause that doesn't parse test packages